# Http query parameters needs to be extract in Java for Mule Application?

Tags: mule

I am new to Mule. My question is how to extract **HTTP parameters** inside a java component. I tried this in Java class of Mule application. The query **param** name is id But it's not actually working 
So far I tried the following: ---

```
MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
String id = message.getInboundProperty("id");
```

I am getting **null** value. How to extract that in Java class. An example will be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy. You can use following in your Java:

```
MuleMessage muleMessage = eventContext.getMessage();
Map<String, String> queryParams = muleMessage.getInboundProperty("http.query.params");
String id=queryParams.get("id");
System.out.println(id);
return muleMessage;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you